# Using the datetime2 package, how do we individually retrieve each of yyyy, yy, mm, dd, mmm, ddd, hhmm, hhmmss, etc.?

Tags: datetime2

Let's say it's now 2019-07-21-082935.

If I'm using the datetime2 package, what commands do I use to individually retrieve each of "2019", "19", "07", "7", "JUL", "July", "21", "SUN", "Sun", "Sunday", "082935", "0829", "08", "29", "35"?

(I was thinking that there'd be some simple commands like \yyyy, \mm, \MMM, \Mm, etc. but there don't seem to be.)

And if the above is not possible, is there some other package I can use?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You could use `\DTMsavenow{mydate}` to store the current date and the various `\DTMfetch...{mydate}` macros to retrieve individual fields of the date (see chapter 4 of the [package documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/datetime2/datetime2.pdf)).

Answer (score 2):

`datetime2` doesn't seem to provide a command to parse date/time format strings and output the specific component. If you only want to access single components, you can easily define a macro that compares an argument against the given format and outputs the corresponding component formatted accordingly.

The below code defines a macro `\formatdatetime{<saved date name>}{<component format>}` that formats a specific component of the saved date according to the passed format. As you haven't been very clear about what string should be mapped to what format, this code should be more considered a sketch of the idea than a full implementation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[calc]{datetime2}

\newcommand\formatdatetime[2]{%
    \begingroup
    \renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{}%
    \renewcommand*\DTMdisplaytime[3]{}%
    \renewcommand*\DTMdisplayzone[2]{}%
    %
    \ifmatches{#2}{yyyy}{\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{\number##1}}%
    \ifmatches{#2}{yy}  {\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{\DTMtwodigits{##1}}}%
    \ifmatches{#2}{m}   {\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{##2}}%
    \ifmatches{#2}{mm}  {\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{\DTMtwodigits{##2}}}%
    \ifmatches{#2}{mmm} {\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{\DTMshortmonthname{##2}}}%
    \ifmatches{#2}{mmmm}{\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{\DTMmonthname{##2}}}%
    \ifmatches{#2}{d}   {\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{##3}}%
    \ifmatches{#2}{dd}  {\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{\DTMtwodigits{##3}}}%
    \ifmatches{#2}{ddd} {\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{\DTMshortweekdayname{##4}}}%
    \ifmatches{#2}{dddd}{\renewcommand*\DTMdisplaydate[4]{\DTMweekdayname{##4}}}%
    %
    \DTMuse{#1}%
    \endgroup
}
\newcommand\ifmatches[3]{%
    \def\tempa{#1}%
    \def\tempb{#2}%
    \ifx\tempa\tempb #3\fi
}

\newcommand\testdatetime[2]{%
    \makebox[4em][l]{#2}: \formatdatetime{#1}{#2}\par
}

\begin{document}
\DTMsavenow{mydate}
\makebox[4em][l]{now}: \DTMuse{mydate}\par
\testdatetime{mydate}{yyyy}
\testdatetime{mydate}{yy}
\testdatetime{mydate}{m}
\testdatetime{mydate}{mm}
\testdatetime{mydate}{mmm}
\testdatetime{mydate}{mmmm}
\testdatetime{mydate}{d}
\testdatetime{mydate}{dd}
\testdatetime{mydate}{ddd}
\testdatetime{mydate}{dddd}
\end{document}
```

outputs

[image]